# How I should use shouldComponentUpdate here to update parent state in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in React.js, and I have an issue with parent component state updating. I attached whole code so that don't miss something that can be important.

I need my 'Reset' button to reset parent component's state

**[HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-napier-bp3bm)** you can see what the issue is.

You should open 'Events' in Navigator menu and try to select categories and then to reset them.

parent component: **components/events/filter-bar.js**

chils component: **components/shared/dropdown/category.js**

Comment: If a parent needs access to a child's state, then that state should likely belong to the parent and be passed down to the child as a prop. Try moving the state into `DropdownGroup` and passing it down as props to `CategoryDropdown`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have categories in `FilterBar` and `Category` components state - which are not in sync. Since `FilterBar` also recieves `categories` as a `prop` - that indicates that you don't have `a single source of truth` for `categories`. There are at least three places where you are keeping categories in different components states. That is very bad thing and leads to bugs and hard to maintain state. Solution is having categories state in just one place and than passing it down to components which need them (together with methods for updating categories).

Anyway, if reseting only dropdown categories is what you want this is what you can do:

1. create a new method in `FilterBar`, name it whatewer you want and pass it as a prop to `Categories` component. This method will accept just one argument - array of categories. This method will update `FilterBar` state.categories.
2. in `Categories` component, remove `state.selected` and `saveSelected` method. In places where you are using `saveSelected` replace it with prop (function/method) passed from `FilterBar`.

#### update

This question actually has nothing to do with component lifecycles or updating parent state.

Here is a thing: you can't control the state you don't own (which is the case with 3rd party components). Some lib authors provide methods for setting initial state or reset, but that is not the case with component library you are using.

In your case, best you can do is to `unmount` dropdowns ad then `mounts` them again. It's something like refreshing just the part of the page.

Do this:

1. add `visible: true` to the `FilterBar` state
2. add `onReset` method to the same component:

```
onReset = () => {
    this.setState(
      state => ({ visible: false }),
      () => {
        this.setState({ visible: true });
      }
    );
  };
```

3. update reset button: `onClick={this.onReset}`
4. conditionally render `ButtonToolbar`:

```
return this.state.visible ? <ButtonToolbar /> : null // have shortened code just for demonstration purpose
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. First, we just write this project as Java developers, so we need just working front end. I agree that understanding react is needed also. Due to task, firstly I did like you say, but this didn't work. Then I tried something with shouldComponentUpdate, and it seemed to work some moment. Now I made changes, could you see if I understood you correctly? You can see new lines as commented in right side and old lines commented themselves.

Comment: Still trying to understand what do you want to accomplsh. Is reseting dropdowns (categories, by mounth & date) all that  you  what?

Comment: Yes, but first I want to check if this works with Categories. Then I will do this with rest components too (I mean pass method as props)

Comment: sorry for this, but it seems that I can't understand you. i believe yo tried what you say and it works. I have added all your advised, but it still doesn't work. Could you take a look to code again? If you don't mind, just correct my mistake and I will see what was wrong just not to waste your time. Hope you will understand

Comment: You were close, but you didn't implement 4th step correctly. Also  `shouldComponentUpdate` doesn't return boolean - which is wrong. Have change it to `componentDidUpdate` with correct signature. `Button` Import was also incorrect. Here is a [link to fixed example](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-dew-qmwm0).

Comment: Thanks! now it works. but when 'Select' categories, it is error, in this link

Comment: Yes, that is another bug in your app. And if I fix it for you than another one will appear. Will need to end this. Imo your issue has been resolved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210648/discussion-between-robert-gurjiev-and-danko).